# Storing plot in object

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to store a simple plot created using plot() in an R object?

Let's say I create a plot:

```
a<-rnorm(1000)
b<-rnorm(1000)
plot(a,type='b')
lines(b,col="blue")
```

I would like to store both the plot and the added line in an object.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Add `temp <- recordPlot()` after your code. You can check it after words by typing `temp` in console

Comment: then can I store multiple versions of temp in a list?

Comment: Yes, I can post a sample code if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that will save your plots in a list.

```
n <- 3
templist <- vector(mode = "list", n)

for(i in seq_along(templist)){
  a <- rnorm(1000)
  b <- rnorm(1000)
  plot(a, type = 'b')
  lines(b,col = "blue")
  templist[[i]] <- recordPlot() 
}
```

You can check each plot, by doing `templist[[i]]` where `i` is in the range of: `1 <= i <= n`